# Validate if a person is older than 18 years given birthday

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datetime

I'm trying to validate if a person is older than 18 years given her/his birthday but it's not working. This is the code I made:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.bootstrapValidator.i18n.age = $.extend($.fn.bootstrapValidator.i18n.age || {}, {
        'default': 'Please enter a valid birthday'
    });

    $.fn.bootstrapValidator.validators.age = {
        html5Attributes: {
            message: 'message',
            minage: 'integer',
            separator: 'separator'
        },
        /**
         * Return true if the input value is a valid RIF.
         *
         * @param {BootstrapValidator} validator The validator plugin instance
         * @param {jQuery} $field Field element
         * @param {Object} options Can consist of the following keys:
         * - message: The invalid message
         * - minage: A integer number with minimum age
         * @returns {Boolean}
         */
        validate: function (validator, $field, options) {
            var value = $field;

            if (value === '') {
                return true;
            }

            // Check wether minage is integer or not
            if (!parseInt(options.minage)) {
                return false;
            }

            // Get the birthday
            var $date = value.val();
            var $split = $date.split(options.separator);

            var $dateFullYear = parseInt($split[2], 10);
            var $dateMonth = parseInt($split[1], 10);
            var $dateDay = parseInt($split[0], 10);

            var $tempDate = new Date($dateFullYear + options.minage, $dateMonth, $dateDay);

            console.log("$dateFullYear" + $dateFullYear);
            console.log("$dateMonth" + $dateMonth);
            console.log("$dateDay" + $dateDay);
            console.log("$tempDate" + $tempDate);

            if ($tempDate <= new Date()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
}(window.jQuery));
```

This is what I get in the console:

```
$dateFullYear 2014
$dateMonth 9
$dateDay 1
$tempDate Fri Oct 01 2032 00:00:00 GMT-0430 (Venezuela Standard Time)
```

And I though the comparison is wrong or I'm doing something wrong since `today/now()` date validates as valid and this is wrong, any advice around my code? Any help?

PS: The code is part of a custom function I made for BootstrapValidator library

Comment: This is very unrelated, but your use of `$` on variable names is confusing, and `var value = field` is redundant when `field` is a string.

Comment: @meagar I updated the post with the real code as I have since it's part of BootstrapValidator library

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. especially since you logged the $tempDate as being 2032 and doing `new Date(2032, 9, 1) <= new Date()` returns false. which is correct.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield yes it's right, I found what is causing the problem, thanks for your time